# ElasticSearch all shards remain unassigned (with routing.allocation set to all)

Tags: elasticsearch

why are none of my shards being assigned? (ES 2.3)

Create index:

```
PUT 'host:9200/entities?pretty' -d ' {
  "mappings": {
      x
    }
  },
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 6, 
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    }
  }
}'
```

Cluster Settings:

```
GET 'host:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty'
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "enable" : "all"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transient" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "enable" : "all"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Cluster:

```
host          master 
node3         m  
node2         m
node1         *
```

Shards

```
GET 'host:9200/_cat/shards?v'
index    shard prirep state      docs store ip node 
entities 5     p      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 5     r      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 1     p      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 1     r      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 4     p      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 4     r      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 2     p      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 2     r      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 3     p      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 3     r      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 0     p      UNASSIGNED                    
entities 0     r      UNASSIGNED
```

I'm able to assign nodes directly through the routing API, but that doesn't seem to be the wait to go.

If I setup the cluster differently, with 1 master node and 2 data nodes, the problem doesn't occur. But

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I misinterpreted `node.master` and `node.data` settings. I thought it had to be either or.

Set all three nodes to `node.master: true` and `node.data: true` , now it's working like a charm.